# GitLab creates empty branches when I make a new merge request

Tags: git, gitlab, branch, merge-request

I have two branches, `2-feat/selecting-interviews` and `development`. In GitLab, I go to issue #2 which is aware of 2-feat and create a merge request. The merge request automatically creates a new branch and makes the merge request about that new branch. You can see that here in this youtube video: https://youtu.be/AMWaFCm0nzU

Can somebody explain why this is happening? Thank you.

Comment: There's no such thing, in Git, as an *empty branch*. A branch name points to some commit; that commit is, by definition, the last commit *in* the branch. We (humans) sometimes tend to think of "a branch" as "the commits in that branch, minus the commits in some other branch(es)", and *that* set may be empty, but there are still lots of commits in the branch: it's just that you've subtracted away all of them, when you subtracted away commits that are also in the other branch.

Comment: Exactly what GitLab is doing, I'm not sure, but if you're doing the mental subtraction, that's how you're getting an "empty branch" and GitLab is just creating a branch name that points to the same last commit as some existing branch, or perhaps even further back in the history than that last commit.

Comment: @torek Sure, yes the branches being created are pointing to the last commit in main, thus it seeming "empty" because there are no changes in it. But as to why GitLab is doing that I would love to have an answer for.

Answer (score 1):

The expectation is apparently that merge requests are created when branches are created, by means of the "create merge request" button. This strikes me as odd, as I create the branch first, make the changes, then do the merge request when it's ready to be reviewed. Nevertheless, if [this issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/31459) is addressed, at least there will be the option to merge the existing branch instead of creating a new branch on the same commit as the current branch.